I'm encountering a DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error when running Selenium tests with Chrome on my GitHub Actions
  - name: Install Specific Chrome
    run: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https curl
      CHROME_VERSION="117.0.5938.62"
      CHROME_DEB="google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}-1_amd64.deb"
      wget https://mirror.cs.uchicago.edu/google-chrome/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/$CHROME_DEB
      sudo dpkg -i $CHROME_DEB || sudo apt-get install -f -y

  - name: Install Compatible ChromeDriver
    run: |
      set -x
      sudo apt-get install -y wget unzip

      CHROME_VERSION="117.0.5938.62"
      MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $CHROME_VERSION | cut -d'.' -f1)

      # Fetch the corresponding ChromeDriver version
      LATEST_DRIVER=$(wget -qO- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$MAJOR_VERSION) || true

      # If unable to fetch the version, fall back to the latest
      if [ -z "$LATEST_DRIVER" ]; then
        echo "Falling back to the latest ChromeDriver version."
        LATEST_DRIVER=$(wget -qO- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE) || { echo "Failed to retrieve the latest ChromeDriver version"; exit 1; }
      fi

      # Remove any existing incompatible ChromeDriver
      sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

      # Download and install the correct version of ChromeDriver
      wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LATEST_DRIVER/chromedriver_linux64.zip || { echo "Failed to download ChromeDriver"; exit 1; }
      unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
      sudo mv chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
      sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
      set +x

And this is my driver initialzation:
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        // Create ChromeOptions and configure them
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--headless");  // Enables headless mode
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");

The error says that:  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
